# Find and return the key with lowest value in association list

Tags: associations

I am still new in Mathematica, and I need some help here. Suppose that I have an association

```
A=Association[1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 4, 7 -> 2, 8 -> 2, 9 -> 2, 10 -> 1, 11 -> 4, 12 -> 1, 13 -> 3, 14 -> 2, 15 -> 3, 16 -> 1]
```

and I want to get the output of key with the lowest value, which is

```
{1, 2, 10, 12, 16}
```

I know that `ArgMin` can't get my desired answer. So I tried `Position[A, Min[A]]`, but instead it gives me the output

```
{{Key[1]}, {Key[2]}, {Key[10]}, {Key[12]}, {Key[16]}}
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You still "will need some help here" after many a years :)

Comment: `PositionIndex[#][Min@#] &[A]` (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149200/106))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
Keys @ MinimalBy[Value]@ A
```

> ```
> {1, "2", 10, 12, 16}
> ```

About your approach, you can add `Part`:

```
Position[A, Min[A]][[All, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: +1. I think, you should definitely keep it.