# Reverse Lookup: getting keys from values

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, rule

`List`s of `Rule`s or `Association`s are both a useful way of mapping between values. It also allows us to use handy functions like

```
Lookup[key]@ rules
(*value*)
(*Alternatively: Lookup[rules, key]*)

Lookup[key]@ assoc
(*value*)
(*Alternatively: Lookup[assoc, key]*)
```

Unfortunately, there is not a built-in reverse, i.e. given the value, what key(s) are associated to that value.

What is an efficient alternative to do so?

Comment: I recommend using an `Association` instead of a`List` if your keys in each `List` are unique. Then you could just use `Position`.

Answer (score 23):

```
 PositionIndex[assoc][<value>]
```

For example:

```
assoc = <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 4, f -> 1|>;
PositionIndex[assoc][1]
```

> {a, d, f}

And

```
PositionIndex[assoc]
```

> <|1 -> {a, d, f}, 2 -> {b}, 3 -> {c}, 4 -> {e}|>

Alternatively:

```
PositionIndex[assoc] // Lookup[4]
```

> {e}

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: @WReach I am surprised that no one thought to post this before (clearly I didn't) but it should be noted that it is slower than a one-off operation with `Position`, or `Pick` for that matter, and it isn't clear from the original question this operation would be repeated or not.

Answer (score 19):

One way would be to "invert" the association and then look up values in the result:

```
$a = <| "a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 1, "d" -> 2, "e" -> 3 |>;


$inv = $a // Normal // GroupBy[Last -> First]

(* <| 1 -> {a, c}, 2 -> {b, d}, 3 -> {e} |> *)


$inv[1]

(* {a, c} *)
```

If the original collection is a list of rules instead of an association, `Normal` can be left out.

If an association has a one-to-one mapping of keys to values then (in V11) there is a built-in, but undocumented, function that does the inversion:

```
$a2 = <| "a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3 |>;

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
AssociationInvert[$a2]

(* <| 1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c |> *)
```

Comment: What version has ``GeneralUtilities`InvertAssociation``? I can't seem to find it on my system.

Comment: @ChipHurst I'm using V11.0.1.  I updated the response to indicate that it is a V11 function.  Thanks.

Comment: (+1) If you don't care about collisions, i.e. the association is a one-to-one map, you can do `invertAssociation[assoc_?AssociationQ] := Association[KeyValueMap[#2 -> #1 &, assoc]]`. It seems to be twice as fast as the `GroupBy` approach.

Comment: Ah, it's `AssociationInvert` not `InvertAssociation`... No wonder I couldn't find it :)

Comment: It's implementation is simply `AssociationInvert [assoc_] := AssociationThread[Values[assoc], Keys[assoc]]`. Should have thought to do that!

Comment: That is clever :)

Answer (score 10):

You may use [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) on an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) to return the [`Key`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html) (or keys) that holds a value.

With

```
assoc = <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 4, f -> 1|>;
```

Then

```
Position[assoc, 4]
```

> ```
> {{Key[e]}}
> ```

```
Position[assoc, 1]
```

> ```
> {{Key[a]}, {Key[d]}, {Key[f]}}
> ```

These can be used with [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html),

```
Extract[Position[assoc, 1]]@assoc
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1}
> ```

Or with [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html)

```
Query[Position[assoc, 1]]@assoc
```

> ```
> {<|a -> 1|>, <|d -> 1|>, <|f -> 1|>}
> ```

or

```
Query[Flatten@Position[assoc, 1]]@assoc
```

> ```
> <|a -> 1, d -> 1, f -> 1|>
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What you have above work, but doesn't quite give what I envisioned as the output. I mean, it works, but you why would you want to Extract the value from the position? You entered it as a parameter, i.e. you already know what it is?  The idea is to get the Key from the Value

Comment: @SumNeuron `Position` gives you the `Key`.  Just showing ways to use the output of `Position` to go the other way as many first-time users don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Good point. I must admit at first I was really bother with Position returning such nested output.

Answer (score 10):

[`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) may be worthy of consideration:

```
kfv = Pick[Keys @ #, Values @ #, #2] &;

rules = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 4, f -> 1};
assoc = <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 4, f -> 1|>;

kfv[rules, 1]
kfv[assoc, 1]
```

> ```
> {a, d, f}
>
> {a, d, f}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

There's a certain elegance to:

```
GroupBy[assoc, Identity, Keys]         (* gives all keys for a given value *)

GroupBy[assoc, Identity, First@*Keys]  (* gives first key for a given value *)
GroupBy[assoc, Identity, Last@*Keys]   (* gives last key for a given value *)
```

But it's no more efficient than @WReach's `GroupBy` solution for all keys, and much less efficient than the `` "GeneralUtilities`" `` solution for the (partial) inverse function he also gives:

```
AssociationInvert[assoc] :=            (* gives last key for a given value *)
 AssociationThread[Values@assoc, Keys@assoc]
```

(The code for `AssociationInvert[]` was first noted by Chip Hurst in a comment.  I thought it deserved a mention in an answer, since it's simple and built out of documented functions.)

Answer (score 4):

you can use `Select` as well:

```
assoc = <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 4, f -> 1|>;
Keys[Select[assoc, # == 1 &]]
```

> {a , d , f}

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the answer of WReach

`AssociationMap[Reverse]` delivers the same result as `AssociationInvert`:

```
asc = <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 4, f -> 1|>;

AssociationMap[Reverse] @ asc
```

(* <|1 -> f, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> e|> *)

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
AssociationInvert[asc]
```

(* <|1 -> f, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> e|> *)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a simple `List` of `Rule`s, e.g.

```
rules = {
a -> 1,
b -> 2,
c -> 3,
d -> 1,
e -> 4,
f -> 1
};
```

The following function allows one to get various amounts of key(s) associated with the specified value, using familiar list operators `First`, `Most`, `Rest`, and `Last`. One can also specify `All` (typically an option) to get All keys associated with value.  In addition, one can specify *which* key they want. The code is at the bottom of this post.

## Examples

Using the rules defined above:

Default: return first instance of a key associated with the value

```
KeyFromValue[rules, 1]
(*a*)
```

Playing around with the option `"Which"`:

```
KeyFromValue[rules, 1, "Which" -> Last]
(*f*)
KeyFromValue[rules, 1, "Which" -> All]
(*{a, d, f}*)
KeyFromValue[rules, 1, "Which" -> Most]
(*{a, d}*)
KeyFromValue[rules, 1, "Which" -> 2]
(*d*)
```

There is some limited error handling:

```
KeyFromValue[rules, 1, "Which" -> 5]
Asked for 5th instance of 1.
Only 3  instances found.
Out: {}

KeyFromValue[rules, 10]
Nothing found
Out: {}
```

## Update

Added alternative definition to handle association:

```
assoc = <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 4, f -> 1|>;

KeyFromValue[rules, 1]
KeyFromValue[assoc, 1]
KeyFromValue[rules, 1, "Which" -> Most]
KeyFromValue[assoc, 1, "Which" -> Most]

a
a
{a, d}
{a, d}
```

## Code

I'm not claiming this is the most efficient means of doing so, but it does serve its purpose. Kudos to anyone who wants to abstract this for any list of rules.

```
Options[KeyFromValue] = {"Which" -> 1, "Verbose" -> False};
KeyFromValue[association_List, value_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[
  {found = First /@ Position[association, value]},

  (*If that value is not found*)
  If[found == {},

   (*Return empty List*)

   If[OptionValue[KeyFromValue, "Verbose"], Print["Nothing found"];]

    Return[{}],

   (*Else rename the position wanted as pos*)

   With[{pos = OptionValue[KeyFromValue, "Which"]},


    (*If pos is a function that returns an unwrapped singular value*)

        If[MemberQ[{First, Last}, pos],
     (*Apply the function. Return it.*)

     Return[First@association[[#]] &@(pos@found)],

     (*If pos is a function that returns a List*)

     If[MemberQ[{Most, Rest}, pos],
      (*Apply the function. Return it.*)

      Return[First /@ (association[[#]] & /@ (pos@found))],

      (*If pos is All (technically not a function)*)

      If[MemberQ[{All}, pos],

       (*Given them everything found*)

       Return[First /@ (association[[#]] & /@ (found))],

       (*Else, check to see if position valid.*)

       If[pos <= Length@found,
        (*If it is, return desired value.*)

        Return[First@association[[found[[pos]]]]],
        (*Else notify user and return {}.*)

        If[OptionValue[KeyFromValue, "Verbose"], 
         Print["Asked for " <> ToString@pos <> "th instance of " <> 
            ToString@value <> ".\nOnly " <> 
            ToString[Length@found]  " instances found."]];
        Return[{}];
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]

    ]
   ]
  ]


Options[KeyFromValue] = {"Which" -> 1, "Verbose" -> False};
KeyFromValue[association_Association, value_, OptionsPattern[]] :=

 Module[
  {found = First /@ First /@ Position[association, value]},

  (*If that value is not found*)
  If[found == {},
   (*Return Missing List*)

   If[OptionValue[KeyFromValue, "Verbose"], Print["Nothing found"];];
   Return[Missing];
   ];

  (*Else rename the position wanted as pos*)

  With[{pos = OptionValue[KeyFromValue, "Which"]},

   (*If pos is a function that returns an unwrapped singular value*)

     If[MemberQ[{First, Last, Most, Rest}, pos],
    (*Apply the function. Return it.*)
    Return[(pos@found)],

    (*If pos is All (technically not a function)*)

    If[MemberQ[{All}, pos],

     (*Given them everything found*)
     Return[(found)],

     (*Else, check to see if position valid.*)

     If[pos <= Length@found,

      (*If it is, return desired value.*)
      Return[found[[pos]]],
      (*Else notify user and return {}.*)

      If[OptionValue[KeyFromValue, "Verbose"], 
       Print["Asked for " <> ToString@pos <> "th instance of " <> 
          ToString@value <> ".\nOnly " <> 
          ToString[Length@found]  " instances found."]];
      Return[{}];
      ]
     ]

    ]

   ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use pattern matching to find the key you're looking for:

```
key = assoc /. <|___, n_ -> value, ___|> -> n
```

The downside is that it will only return the first match it finds so this is only good for 1 to 1 associations.